# Pivot control stopped working in MVVM on WP8

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8, pivot

I am new bee in MVVM and am facing issues using the pivot control. The code works in windows hone 7 sdk but not for windows phone 8 sdk.

Here is the code:

ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DocumentDetailsItemRowTemplate}"
                                Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}" >

I am getting the header correctly but nothing is displayed below it.

Answer (score 0):

There have been some small changes to the template for these controls in WP8. For further details, see the blog post [Panorama and Pivot moved and changed in WP8](http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2013/01/pivot-and-panorama-have-moved-and.html)